# Trying to get a bunch of images to show in succession when touching screen on Swift

Tags: swift, view, sprite, xcode11

I put the different images to show in succession in the assets.xcassets folder as shooter, shooter1, shooter2 and so on but whenever i touch the screen the animation/image shown in the view doesn't change?

Here is my code:

```
 import UIKit
 import SpriteKit

 class ShooterScene: SKScene
 {

     var score = 0
     var enemyCount = 10
     var shooterAnimation = [SKTexture]()

     override func didMove(to view: SKView)
     {
         self.initShooterScene()
     }

     func initShooterScene()
     {
         let shooterAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "shooter") // referencing shooter.atlas
         for index in 1...shooterAtlas.textureNames.count
         {
             let imgName = "shooter\(index)"
             shooterAnimation += [shooterAtlas.textureNamed(imgName)]
         }
     }

     //Animate the shooter

     override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
         if let shooterNode  = self.childNode(withName: "shooterNode") as? SKSpriteNode
         {
             let animation = SKAction.animate(with: shooterAnimation, timePerFrame: 0.1)
             shooterNode.run(animation)
         }
      }



  }
```

The sprite node that I use in the view has the name shooterNode but the image doesn't seem to change at all. Any help would be great

edit:

console output:
     2020-01-23 17:47:59.470204-0500 Tutorial 31 - Introduction to Sprike 
     Kit[5666:203542] Metal API Validation Enabled
     2020-01-23 17:47:59.715838-0500 Tutorial 31 - Introduction to Sprike 
     Kit[5666:203542] SKView: ignoreRenderSyncInLayoutSubviews is NO. Call 
     _renderSynchronouslyForTime without handler
     2020-01-23 17:48:11.764763-0500 Tutorial 31 - Introduction to Sprike 
     Kit[5666:203964] XPC connection interrupted
     2020-01-23 17:48:11.765810-0500 Tutorial 31 - Introduction to Sprike 
     Kit[5666:203968] [connection] Connection interrupted: will attempt to 
     reconnect
     2020-01-23 17:48:11.765887-0500 Tutorial 31 - Introduction to Sprike 
     Kit[5666:205206] [ServicesDaemonManager] interruptionHandler is 
     called. -[FontServicesDaemonManager connection]_block_invoke
     Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 15

Comment: Did you set your shooter node's name property to "shooterNode"? After setting that. Your code worked for me.

Comment: If you mean the sprite property yes I've done that. It still doesn't work. I'm wondering if it's the way I first put the sprite into the view? I dragged the image directly from the shooter.atlas folder because I don't see any other option of putting the sprite into the view?

Comment: I also get this output from the console. Please see the above edit

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code modified. It works for me. Without more code, I don't know how you are setting up your shooter node so I can't replicate your issue.

```
class ShooterScene: SKScene {

    var textures = [SKTexture]()

    //Also serves as the name of the texture the node uses.
    let NODE_NAME:String = "shooter"

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
        //Better the setup scene in intializer, because didMove(to view) is called multiple times.
        //You only want to call the setup method once.
        self.setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    func setup() {

       //Node setup
       let shooterNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: NODE_NAME)
       shooterNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
       shooterNode.name = NODE_NAME
       addChild(shooterNode)

       //Create animation collection
       let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: NODE_NAME)
        //Arrays start at index zero so we need to subtract 1 from the total textures count
        let upperBound = atlas.textureNames.count - 1
        for index in 1...upperBound {
            let textureName = "\(NODE_NAME)\(index)"
            textures += [atlas.textureNamed(textureName)]
        }
    }

    //Animate the shooter when screen pressed.
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        guard let shooterNode = self.childNode(withName: NODE_NAME) as? SKSpriteNode else { return }
        //For animations that are around 60 Frames per second
        let FPS:Double = 1/60
        let animation = SKAction.animate(with: self.textures, timePerFrame: FPS)
        shooterNode.run(animation)
    }



 }
```

Comment: I've posted an edit of what my xcode looks like on the shooterscene.sks. Is there anything I'm doing wrong from what you can see?